# Trying to include files in plugin isn't working

Tags: plugins, php, include

I've created a simple site specific functions plugin but I'm having some trouble including additional files to it.

Basically I'm trying to keep things separated so I've got one php file for general functions (The default plugin file) and another for custom post types and taxonomies.

Here's a sample of my current code, does anyone know where I'm going wrong?;

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Functions Plugin
Description: Site specific functions
*/

include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'types.php');

/* General Functions Here */

?>
```

Comment: Try without using plugin_dir_path() function like this include( 'types.php');

Comment: Are you sure the file is named exactly `types.php` and it exists in the **same** folder of plugin file? How have you tested that the including is not working? Have you tried your plugin with only this code? If you replace `include` with `require` what happen?

Comment: I tried that to start with, I just got the white screen of death.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, I've tried all of those things. The file is 100% called types.php and is in the same folder

Comment: I can't be sure, but seems there is some fatal error in your 'types.php'

Comment: Can you just create another demo file and check whether it's including or not or try commenting all code 'types.php' file? Just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
include(plugins_url( 'types.php' , __FILE__ ));
```

or

```
$p_url=plugins_url();
$types_url=$url.'/your-plugin-name/types.php';
include($types_url);
```

Note:
don't forgot about path if have that file in a sub folder like inc or js,assets. Mention them

Comment: `plugins_url` works? Are you testing on local environmnet, don't you? I bet this will not work on online server. [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is often disabled on webservers, and it should be so. @Poisontonomes